# Помогите вывести из базы нужную информацию. Postgresql, Python

Tags: python, postgresql

Есть следующая информация:

```
Date        Player               timeOnIce
----------  -------------------  -----------
2022-01-08  Justin Schultz       15:59
2022-01-08  Garnet Hathaway      12:35
2022-01-08  Conor Sheary         18:35
2022-01-08  Michael Sgarbossa    10:23
2022-01-08  Nick Jensen          17:19
2022-01-08  Alex Ovechkin        20:55
2022-01-08  Evgeny Kuznetsov     17:37
2022-01-08  Trevor van Riemsdyk  19:46
2022-01-08  Dmitry Orlov         19:49
2022-01-08  Daniel Sprong        18:24
...
....
```

Я её поместим в базу, в таблицу, созданную так:

```
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS players (DATE varchar(32) NOT NULL, NAME varchar(32), TIME_ON_ICE varchar(32))')
```

Помещал вот так:

```
for line in players_table:s
    line = [str(i) for i in line]
    sql_string = """ INSERT INTO players (DATE, NAME, TIME_ON_ICE) VALUES (%s,%s,%s) """
    record_to_insert = tuple(line)
    cur.execute(sql_string, record_to_insert)
    conn.commit()
```

Как мне вывести из таблицы топ-3 игроков с наибольшим Time on ice? Правильно ли я создал саму таблицу? Подозреваю, что timeOnIce должно быть в формате времени.

Comment: используйте для `time_on_ice` тип `interval` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-datetime.html, тогда обычная сортировка сделает то, что вам нужно. При вставке на стороне питона используйте объекты [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta)

Comment: @RomanKonoval, подскажите, у меня время в минутах и секундах. По умолчанию после вставки в таблицу, судя по всему, python думает, что там часы и минуты. На первом месте после сортировки у меня ('2022-01-16', 'Morgan Rielly', datetime.timedelta(days=1, seconds=13260), вставлял я 2022-01-16 Morgan Rielly 27:41. Как мне правильно было бы перевести datetime.timedelta в минуты и секунды?

Comment: Показывайте конкретный код со значениями (редактируйте текст вопроса). Так в общем не понятно, что вы делаете не так.